# How can I obtain the AAD Token from HoloLens 2?

Tags: token, hololens

The HoloLens 2 is Azure Joined and Im logged in as a user and I want to get the HoloLens 2 AAD Token to authenticate against some APIs.

My thoughts are that I can grab the token that is already on the HoloLens 2.

I can´t find any documentation online.

Where can I find it and which class can I use?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to [Manage user identity and login for HoloLens | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/hololens/hololens-identity), you need to use the [Windows Account Manager API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.Core?view=winrt-22621), and you can refer to examples from [Windows-universal-samples/Samples/WebAccountManagement at main · microsoft/Windows-universal-samples · GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/WebAccountManagement).

Comment: Thanks! I tried to implement it using WebAccountProvider but it supports only one Resource. I have 3 API Links that Id like to use. How can I do that?

Comment: What does 3 API Links mean? Does it mean Account? If so, Azure AD can support more than 1 account on HoloLens 2 device.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I need an AAD/Entra token in the HoloLens 2. I have no problem getting it in a PC because it can use the interactive authentication flow. I can't make that work in HoloLens 2. The docs suggested by @ZuochengWang-MSFT are of no value in this case.